# Does boto.dynamodb2 support storing a dict of dicts?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

**Solution:** Updating to the brand-new boto 2.35.2 fixed the problem.

---

How can I store a dict of dicts in DynamoDB using boto?

The straightforward approach that I've been trying doesn't seem to work.  Trying to save an item defined this way:

```
data = {
    'id': '123456',
    'foo': {'hello': 'world'}
}

item = Item(my_table, data=data)
item.save(overwrite=True)
```

generates this exception:

```
TypeError: Unsupported type "<type 'dict'>" for value "{'hello': 'world'}"
```

I've seen [conflicting information](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2192) on the web about whether this is supported.  I can't get it to work; am using boto 2.35.1.

---

Here's a complete example that demonstrates the problem:

```
import boto.dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.fields import HashKey
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
from boto.dynamodb2.items import Item

conn = boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')

my_table = Table.create('my_table',
                        connection=conn,
                        schema=[
                            HashKey('id')
                        ])

my_table = Table('my_table')

data = {
    'id': '123456',
    'foo': {'hello': 'world'}
}

item = Item(my_table, data=data)
item.save(overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB API now supports map and list object:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataFormat.html

And seams that last boto version (yesterday at the time I answered) added this too:

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes/v2.35.2.html

but personally I didn't play with yet.